# Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT when Connecting to MongoDB Atlas Cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongodb-atlas, connection-timeout

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster from my Node.js application. The error message I'm receiving is "querySrv ETIMEOUT." This problem seems to arise during the process of querying the SRV records for the MongoDB cluster. Despite having followed the correct steps to set up the connection and ensure the validity of the connection string, I'm unable to establish a connection successfully.

This error has halted the generation of a page in my application. I've checked my network connectivity, DNS resolution capabilities, and firewall settings, but the problem persists. The MongoDB cluster appears to be up and running as well. I suspect there might be an issue with how the DNS queries are being handled or a potential problem with the cluster's configuration.

I've already attempted various troubleshooting steps, including checking the connection string, verifying my MongoDB Atlas cluster's status, and inspecting my firewall and proxy settings for any obstructions to outbound connections. Despite these efforts, the error remains.

If anyone has encountered a similar "querySrv ETIMEOUT" error when connecting to MongoDB Atlas clusters or has expertise in networking-related issues, I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this problem and successfully establish a connection to the MongoDB cluster.

I attempted to establish a connection to a MongoDB Atlas cluster using the provided connection string, directly from my Visual Studio Code (VSCode) environment. My expectation was that the connection would be successfully established, enabling me to interact with the database seamlessly. However, during this connection process, I encountered a "querySrv ETIMEOUT" error.

To troubleshoot this issue within VSCode, I undertook the following steps:

Checked my network connectivity within VSCode to ensure that my development environment could access external resources.
Verified DNS resolution capabilities from within VSCode by running a DNS resolution test using appropriate code snippets. This test indicated that DNS resolution was functional within the VSCode environment.
Examined any potential firewall or proxy settings specific to my VSCode environment, ensuring that they were not impeding outbound connections.
Verified the correctness of the MongoDB Atlas connection string used within the VSCode environment.
Despite taking these measures, the error message persisted, preventing the successful establishment of the MongoDB connection directly from within VSCode.

I am reaching out for assistance in understanding why the "querySrv ETIMEOUT" error is occurring exclusively when attempting to connect from within VSCode, and how to overcome this issue. Any insights, guidance, or potential solutions to resolve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the network firewall blocks it.

Comment: How can I activate it ?

Comment: Talk to your IT/network department

Comment: @SoorjyakantaSethy have you got it out why? im using Atlas and having the same issue with node.js mongodb lib; but Studio 3T also from local machine always connects successfully

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and i changed my DNS config to a public DNS(specifically, i choose Google's public DNS). This changed my error.
However there are still chances that you will encounter this error again even if the DNS has been changed. Reason why i said that is, i encountered this situation, that's why even i am here writing this.
Try changing DNS, maybe this could help your situation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, my ISP doesn't resolve multiple levels of subdomains in Atlas URL

Solution:

- Windows control panel >> Network and Sharing
- Adapter settings
- Right-click on LAN or Wifi >> Properties
- Click IPv4 >> Properties
- Use the following DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4